# MongoError: Authentication failed for node.js app using Docker containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have created a node app using MongoDB as a database. I created containers for both of them and created a docker-compose file. But while connecting MongoDB with my node app I am getting an Authentication failed error. I want to connect my node container with the MongoDB container using docker-compose. I have set all the credentials but I am getting an Authentication failed error.

error:

```
api        |     MongoError: Authentication failed.
api        |     at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:272:20)
api        |     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
api        |     at processIncomingData (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
api        |     at MessageStream._write (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
api        |     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
api        |     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
api        |     at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
api        |     at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
api        |     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
api        |     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
api        |     at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
api        |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
api        |   ok: 0,
api        |   code: 18,
api        |   codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
api        | }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: api
    volumes:
      - /home/app/node_modules
      - ./server:/home/app
    ports:
      - 8000:5000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mongodb
    networks:
      - lib_api

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INTIDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INTIDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - lib_api

networks: 
  lib_api:
    driver: bridge

volumes: 
  mongodb-data:
    driver: local
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=developement
MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME=niranjan
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
DB_NAME=library
```

dbconfig.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("database connected"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this mongodb uri:

```
MONGODB_URI='mongodb://root:1004@<your_mongo_service_name>/<your_db_Name>?authSource=admin&w=1'
```

Comment: After reading this answer I looked up [this link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options), to confirm that I needed to set the option `authSource` to the correct database (admin also in my case). Thanks, debugging that took embarrassingly long.